# Onelogin java saml for providing access

Tags: java, playframework, single-sign-on, saml, autologin

I am developing an Admin console for my application(frontend angular-js , backend java in play framework),
i want to authorise it by [onelogin](https://www.onelogin.com/) using saml

i read [onelogin development document](https://developers.onelogin.com/v1.0/page/saml-toolkit-for-java) , but it is not working , because i didn't get their sbt.

please suggest me the right direction. or any another approach, google not helping me, its only confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use play or `OneLogin toolkit`, but I have had success with `OpenSAML`, `OneLogin` with help from: http://blog.samlsecurity.com/.

You will need metadata from `OneLogin`, to be able to parse the response. Request is simple GET (unless you need special kind of request - in that case you will need to build it yourself and send as `?SAMLRequest=...` base64 encoded).

Take a look at blog, there are examples of parsing response, building request, and loading/checking metadata.